# vuex -> store gone with 'refresh'

Tags: nuxt.js

in my nuxt.js application I have configured a store where I set default value which change with specific actions. However, if I e.g. go directly to a page, then the store information can't be used. I get an error `[nuxt.js] Cannot load components TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined at Object.data`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's working as intended as Vuex doesn't keep the state for refreshes. You need to fetch and fill the store again using NuxtServerInit action in Your store. Read the docs first please, it's all in there.

Answer (score 0):

Try `persistedState` `Vuex` plugin.

And fetch your data in `nuxtServerInit` action in `Vuex`.

Comment: @executable Cause it's a different approach, as You dont need to fetch and fill the store everytime, You can keep it persisted and only update it if needed with nuxtServerInit.